# How to find distance between two points using latitude and longitude

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a ROUTES table which has columns SOURCE_AIRPORT and DESTINATION_AIRPORT and describes a particular route that an airplane would take to get from one to the other.

I have an AIRPORTS table which has columns LATITUDE and LONGITUDE which describes an airports geographic position.

I can join the two tables using columns which they both share called SOURCE_AIRPORT_ID and DESTINATION_AIRPORT_ID in the routes table, and called IATA in the airports table (a 3 letter code to represent an airport such as LHR for London Heathrow).

My question is, how can I write an SQL query using all of this information to find, for example, the longest route out of a particular airport such as LHR?

I believe I have to join the two tables, and for every row in the routes table where the source airport is LHR, look at the destination airport's latitude and longitude, calculate how far away that is from LHR, save that as a field called "distance", and then order the data by the highest distance first. But in terms of SQL syntax i'm at a loss.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Im actually using openflights data from this website, the relevant data is here in routes.dat and airports.dat : https://openflights.org/data.html

Answer (score 0):

This would have probably been a better question for the Mathematics Stack Exchange, but I’ll provide some insight here. If you are relatively farmiliar with trigonometry, I’m sure you could understand the implementation given this resource: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula. You are looking to compute the distance between two point on the surface of a sphere in terms of their distance across its surface (not a straight line, you can’t travel through the Earth).

The page displays this formula:
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/a65dbbde43ff45bacd2505fcf32b44fc7dcd8cc0

Where 
•   φ1, φ2 are the latitude of point 1 and latitude of point 2 (in radians), 
•   λ1, λ2 are the longitude of point 1 and longitude of point 2 (in radians).
￼
If you data is in degrees, you can simply convert to radians by multiplying by pi/180

Comment: Thank you! That really helped me understand the calculation part, but i think the reason I posted it here was because I'm not sure how to go about phrasing this query in SQL syntax.

Comment: I’m glad this helped! On the aspect of the programming, I am familiar with a variety of languages, but unfortunately SQL is not one of them. I’m sure, however, that someone on this site would be more suited to assist you with that question.

Comment: How familiar are with with SQL? If I provided a code sample written in Python or pseudocode or something, do you feel you could translate it?

Comment: Yeah I know the basics of SQL but this query is a little too complex for me. If you were ever to write the logic in python I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Sure, I’ll provide a code sample now. I’m on a phone, not desktop right now, so sorry if there’s any Python syntax errors. I’m just trying to provide a pseudocode procedure of the logic in a sense.

Comment: Actually, I feel that the last paragraph of your question shows you fully understand the required procedure for this, so I’m not sure a pseudocode example would really help that much more. I just hope someone can help with the SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula called *great circle distance* to calculate distance between two points. You probably can load is as a library for your operating system. Forget the haversine, our planet is not a perfect sphere.
If you use this value often, save it in your `routes` table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're about 90% there in terms of the solution method. I'll add in some additional detail regarding a potential SQL query to get your answer. So there's 2 steps you need to do to calculate the distances - step 1 is to create a table containing joining the ROUTES table to the AIRPORTS table to get the latitude/longitude for both the SOURCE_AIRPORT and DESTINATION_AIRPORT on the route. This might look something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, CONVERT(FLOAT, t2.LATITUDE) AS SOURCE_LAT, CONVERT(FLOAT, t2.LONGITUDE) AS SOURCE_LONG, CONVERT(FLOAT, t3.LATITUDE) AS DEST_LAT, CONVERT(FLOAT, t3.LONGITUDE) AS DEST_LONG, 0.00 AS DISTANCE_CALC
INTO ROUTE_CALCULATIONS 
FROM ROUTES t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN AIRPORTS t2 ON t1.SOURCE_AIRPORT_ID = t2.IATA 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN AIRPORTS t3 ON t1.DESTINATION_AIRPORT_ID = t3.IATA;
```

The resulting output should create a new table titled ROUTE_CALCULATIONS made up of all the ROUTES columns, the longitude/latitude for both the SOURCE and DESTINATION airports, and a placeholder DISTANCE_CALC column with a value of 0.

Step 2 is calculating the distance. This should be a relatively straightforward calculation and update.

```
UPDATE ROUTE_CALCULATIONS 
SET DISTANCE_CALC = 2 * 3961 * asin(sqrt((sin(radians((DEST_LAT- SOURCE_LAT) / 2))) ^ 2 + cos(radians(SOURCE_LAT)) * cos(radians(DEST_LAT)) * (sin(radians((DEST_LONG- SOURCE_LONG) / 2))) ^ 2))
```

And that should give the calculated distance in the DISTANCE_CALC table for all routes seen in the data. From there you should be able to do whatever distance-related route analysis you want.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful, thank you so much, but in SQLite i cant use most of those math functions to work out the distance so im not sure what to do now

Comment: Hmm I've never used SQLite, I take it there's no library you could potentially import to perform functions?